# Как исправить ошибку DI в nest.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Для начала о цели: я хочу понять как в nestjs можно импортировать библиотеку через контейнеры. Вполне вероятно, что знания из angular тоже здесь помогут. И так, есть класс `AuthService`:

```
export class AuthService {
   constructor(
     @Inject('JWT') private jsonWebToken: any,
   ){}
  ....
}
```

Так же провайдер для JWT:

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import constants from '../../../constants';

const jwtProvider = {
  provide: constants.JWT,
  useValue: jwt,
};

@Module({
  components: [jwtProvider],
})
export class JWTProvider {}
export type JsonWebToken = typeof jwt;
```

И модуль для библиотек:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import {BcryptProvider} from './bcrypt/bcrypt.provider';
import {JWTProvider} from './jsonwebtoken/jwt.provider';

@Module({
  components: [
    BcryptProvider,
    JWTProvider,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  exports: [
    BcryptProvider,
    JWTProvider,
  ],
})
export class LibrariesModule{
}
```

В итоге я получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (?). Please verify whether [0] argument is available in the current context.
    at Injector.<anonymous> (D:\Learning\nest\project\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:156:23)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (D:\Learning\nest\project\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:4:58)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Кстате, хотелось бы еще услышать рекомендации о том, как не использовать тип `any` для переменной `jsonWebToken`.